# access values of an object javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iteration, destructure

I am a beginning in javascript. So i have this data with the basic structure like so...

```
{
"status": "active",
"experimental": false,
"expansion": {
    "extension": [
        {
            "valueBoolean": true
        }
    ],
    "contains": [
        {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "8989938493",
            "display": "Acute"
        },
        {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "889080980089",
            "display": "Chronic"
        },
        {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "889080980089",
            "display": "Fragile"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I want to iterate over "contains" and put the values of "display" in an array so i can use it in a react component. I am currently struggling to achieve that. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the actual problem is? The title talks about accessing a property of an object? In the question its "how to iterate an array" + "how to access a property...".

Comment: Have a look at `Array.prototype.map()`

Comment: thank you. will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let res = [];
const obj = {
"status": "active",
"experimental": false,
"expansion": {
    "extension": [
        {
            "valueBoolean": true
        }
    ],
    "contains": [
        {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "8989938493",
            "display": "Acute"
        },
        {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "889080980089",
            "display": "Chronic"
        },
        {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "889080980089",
            "display": "Fragile"
        }
    ]
}
}

obj.expansion.contains.forEach(el => res.push(el.display));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Why the re-invention of `Array.prototype.map()`?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your code works fine here but throws               " Server Error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'expansion' of undefined"                         in my code. Console.log(data) of the fetched data works fine. don't know what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `map` function to transform an array:

```js
const myObject = {
"status": "active",
"experimental": false,
"expansion": {
    "extension": [
        {
            "valueBoolean": true
        }
    ],
    "contains": [
        {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "8989938493",
            "display": "Acute"
        },
        {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "889080980089",
            "display": "Chronic"
        },
        {
            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
            "code": "889080980089",
            "display": "Fragile"
        }
    ]
}
}

const arr = myObject.expansion.contains.map(({display})=>display)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your code works fine here but throws               " Server Error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'expansion' of undefined"                         in my code. Console.log(data) of the fetched data works fine. don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Unhandled Runtime Error

ReferenceError: res is not defined